# What is wrong with my layer-list drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, floating-action-button, layer-list, shapedrawable

I wanted to set a custom drawable to be the android:src of FloatingActionButton in this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sscce="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        sscce:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_drawable" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was expecting something like:

[image]

But I got:

[image]

Here is the custom layer-list drawable, which contains a few shape drawables:

**res/drawable/fab_drawable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#1AFF00" /> <!-- green -->
            <size android:width="150dp"
                android:height="150dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FC00FF" /> <!-- pink -->
            <size android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#0040FF" /> <!-- blue -->
            <size android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <stroke android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#FF0000"/> <!-- red -->

            <solid android:color="#FFBF00" /> <!-- yellow -->
            <size android:width="24dp"
                android:height="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: @BobMalooga Sorry, my bad! Just edited the question and posted the entire file. If you think I should post the rest of the code (like the main activity - though it has nothing special), lemme know.

Comment: No, that's irrelevant.

Comment: Apparently, your drawable should work just fine. As an alternative, you could use a VectorDrawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is syntactically possible to use `dp` values, this seems to cause problems with some density categories, so better use `px` instead. 
Shape drawables will be scaled to fit their containing `View` anyway, the values you provide just have an influence on the proportions of the shape.

For your layer-list drawable, you have to provide a common "frame" for the size of all the shape drawables as each layer will be scaled to fit the `View` independently of the others.

This means that the smaller circles need some additional information about how far from the edge they should be drawn. For a circle centered in its container:

**distance = (container_size - circle_size) / 2**

If we take `150px` as the basic size for all the drawables, then for example the pink circle (size `100px`) needs `25px` distance to the edges of its container.

You can provide this information by setting attributes to each `item`:

```
<item android:top="25px" android:left="25px" android:bottom="25px"  android:right="25px">
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FC00FF" /> <!-- pink -->
    <size android:width="100px"
          android:height="100px"/>
</shape>
</item>
```

Note that it's important to have attributes not only for top/ left but also for bottom/ right. If you leave out any attributes then the drawable will be scaled to touch the respective edge, so the circle shape could be rendered as an oval or as an off-center circle.